# gulp-rsync ignores symbolic links

Tags: gulp

I want to synchronize a directory, which contains a symbolic link. This link should be transferred as symbolic link.

The documentation of [gulp-rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rsync#links) explains the option `links` which seems to cover this.

First problem with `gulp.src` (which does not support symbolic links) can be solved by using [vinyl-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-fs). Works fine except the symbolic link, which is ignored, although listed by `gulpDebug()`.

The used `gulpfile.js` task looks like:

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      gulpDebug = require('gulp-debug'),
      merge = require('merge-stream'),
      rsync = require('gulp-rsync'),
      vfs = require('vinyl-fs');

gulp.task('rsyncFiles', function (done) {
    const rsyncSrcClient =
        vfs.src('src/**')
            .pipe(gulpDebug())
            .pipe(rsync({
                root: 'src/',
                hostname: remoteHostname,
                destination: remoteTargetDir + '/src/',
                links: true
            }));

    return merge(rsyncSrcClient);
});
```

Using `rsync --link ...` manually from shell works as desired, the symbolic link is transferred as symbolic link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the option **`emptyDirectories: true`** solves the problem.

The `gulpfile.js` is now:

```
gulp.task('rsyncFiles', function (done) {
    const rsyncSrcClient =
        vfs.src('src/**')
            .pipe(gulpDebug())
            .pipe(rsync({
                root: 'src/',
                hostname: remoteHostname,
                destination: remoteTargetDir + '/src/',
                links: true,
                emptyDirectories: true
            }));

    return merge(rsyncSrcClient);
});
```

Reason is the filtering mechanism inside the file [node_modules/gulp-rsync/index.js](https://github.com/jerrysu/gulp-rsync/blob/8b0f7d1ee33e7c557be196b7dbf1d404bb5346b5/index.js#L49).

On [index.js#L49](https://github.com/jerrysu/gulp-rsync/blob/8b0f7d1ee33e7c557be196b7dbf1d404bb5346b5/index.js#L49) there is the following source-snippet which is always `false` for symbolic links:

```
sources = sources.filter(function(source) {
    return !source.isNull() ||
           options.emptyDirectories ||
           (source.path === cwd && options.recursive);
});
```

Adding the option `emptyDirectories: true` changes this behavior to result `true` for symbolic links. Symbolic links are not longer filtered out and rsync is transferring the link as desired.